# Is there a way to define macros/alias in psql?

Tags: postgresql, psql

It is somewhat annoying to type `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, VERBOSE)` in `psql` tool every time you tune queries.

So, is there a way to define an aliases (autocompletable ones would be *very* nice) in `psql` similar to the way it is in `bash`?

E.g. `FULLEXPLAIN SELECT * FROM pg_stat;` results into `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, VERBOSE) SELECT * FROM pg_stat;`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
\set fullexplain EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, VERBOSE)

:fullexplain SELECT * FROM pg_stat;.
```

Probably not the most elegant thing I admit.

Also you could put this in [`.psqlrc`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#AEN88713).

Comment: so the macro should be between `:` and `.` ?

Comment: When I run this it expands to `EXPLAIN(ANALYZE,BUFFERS,VERBOSE) select * from pg_stat;`, with all the spaces removed in `EXPLAIN ...`. Is there a way to avoid that? (psql --version -> 15.5)